# Creating a dynamic repeater based on conditions and numeric values upon selecting an option from a Select box in FilamentPHP

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I am developing an application using Laravel FilamentPHP. However, I have a specific requirement where I want to create a dynamic repeater based on the selected option from a Select box, considering certain conditions and numeric values. Once the repeater is generated, I need to be able to save the data.

How can I achieve this functionality using FilamentPHP? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

`````
                ->label('Course')
                ->options(
                    Course::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray()
                )
                ->reactive()
                ->default(2)
                ->afterStateUpdated(function (callable $set, callable $get) {
                    $course = Course::find($get('course_id'));
                    if ($course) {
                        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
                            // $set('repeater_details.repeater.defaultItems', [$i]);
                            $set('repeater_details.repeater.user_id', 12);
                            $set('repeater_details.repeater.type', 1);
                        }
                    }
                })
                ->searchable(),````
`````

Comment: what I understand is, once you select the value from the Select. you need to generate repeater fields, correct?

Comment: yes exactly it is

Comment: @BatuhanHazarGÜLER did you find a solution?